# How can I publish a opecv Mat as a topic and subscribe by rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int trajectory[3] = {512,612,712};
    cv::Mat image(1024,1024,CV_8UC3);

    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cv::circle(image, cv::Point(trajectory[i],trajectory[i]), 100, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
    }

#if 0
    cv::namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::resizeWindow("image", 1024,1024);
    cv::imshow("image", image);   
    cv::waitKey(0);   
    cv::destroyWindow("image"); 
#endif

#if 1
    ros::init(argc, argv, "draw_circle");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it_(n);
    image_transport::Publisher image_pub_ = it_.advertise("/traj_output", 1);

    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr(new cv_bridge::CvImage);

#if 1
    ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
cv_ptr->encoding = "bgr8";
    cv_ptr->header.stamp = time;
    cv_ptr->header.frame_id = "/traj_output";
#endif

    cv_ptr->image = image;
    image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());

    ROS_INFO("ImageMsg Send.");
#endif
    ros::spin();
    return 0;

}
```

this is a pseudo code for learning cv_bridge written by myself.
i have create a new image with several circles drew on it
and transform into a image msgs and publish as a topic
however, the image cannot be shown by rviz

anyone have any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/103911/how-can-i-publish-a-opecv-mat-as-a-topic-and-subscribe-by-rviz/) by [Ronald Chen](https://answers.ros.org/users/4726/ronald-chen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ronald!

I think the problem happens because when you run your node, the image is published only once and then you start RViz, but when you start RViz, your node is not publishing anymore.

In order to see it on RViz, your node should keep publishing at least until RViz is subscribed.

You can see if RViz is subscribed by checking how many nodes are subscribed to the topic. You can achieve this with `image_pub_.getNumSubscribers()`.

Or you can also keep publishing "forever" no matter how many subscribers are there.

I have modified your code, so now you can see the image on `RViz` or `rqt_image_view` without any problem. You can see it working on [a video](https://youtu.be/vCNnq0Hk4cQ) if you want.

The modified code is:

```
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>

namespace enc = sensor_msgs::image_encodings;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int trajectory[3] = {512,612,712};
    cv::Mat image(1024,1024,CV_8UC3);

    for(int i = 0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cv::circle(image, cv::Point(trajectory[i],trajectory[i]), 100, CV_RGB(255,0,0));
    }

#if 0
    cv::namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::resizeWindow("image", 1024,1024);
    cv::imshow("image", image);   
    cv::waitKey(0);   
    cv::destroyWindow("image"); 
#endif


#if 1
    ros::init(argc, argv, "draw_circle");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it_(n);
    image_transport::Publisher image_pub_ = it_.advertise("/traj_output", 1);
        
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr(new cv_bridge::CvImage);
            

    ros::Rate loop_rate(10); //10 hz
    while(ros::ok()){
        
        
        #if 1
            ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
            cv_ptr->encoding = "bgr8";
            cv_ptr->header.stamp = time;
            cv_ptr->header.frame_id = "/traj_output";
        #endif
        
            cv_ptr->image = image;
            image_pub_.publish(cv_ptr->toImageMsg());
        
            ROS_INFO("ImageMsg Sent.");
            ROS_INFO("Subscribers: %d", image_pub_.getNumSubscribers());
        
        
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
    }
#endif
    
    ros::spin();
    return 0;

}
```

Now you can run `rosrun rviz rviz` or `rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view` and select the desired `/traj_output` topic to see the image.

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) with karma: 1038 on 2018-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0